# Is it possible to upgrade a managed package from different salesforce sandbox than the original from which it was created?

Tags: managed-package, package-install

We have a managed package created from older sandbox from which we lost control. But I have source code and another sandbox(test and production) on which this package is installed.

We made some changes on source code and tested on the scratch sandbox. Now, we want to create a package that is an upgraded version of the original package. Since creating a new package and uninstalling older package might cause data-loss.

So, Is it possible to upgrade a managed package from different salesforce sandbox than the original from which it was created?

Comment: Any chance that you mean salesforce environment instead of salesforce sandbox in title and body of question? Have you tried to contact Salesforce to restore access to original environment where package has been created?

Comment: I meant a different instance of salesforce independent with each other(the one in which package was created and the one that we are currently using). Contacting salesforce won't be beneficial as the one who created the package on free developer edition is not in our contact and we don't legally have access to that. But before leaving, they provided the source code.

Comment: Well, since it is a free dev org, then you can ask one who made that for the given org (base on your agreement with given side)

Comment: That's the problem. No contact with the one who initially developed it.

Answer (score 3):

No. Each managed package is tied to a specific developer org. It cannot be migrated to another developer edition org. If you've lost access to that developer edition, you will have no way to upgrade the package, and you would need to create and install a new package. It would have a different namespace, though, so you could install them side-by-side, copy the data, then uninstall the old package. This would still require significant work, but at least you wouldn't lose your data in the interim.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the new package couldn't be installed as the error displayed is _Duplicate Name_.

Comment: @forgotten.boi That doesn't sound like a managed package to me. Is this an unmanaged package?

Comment: My bad, the new package, I installed was unmanaged. Installation is successful. Thanks